# Sending mail with PHP mail() on a Linode

Tags: php, email, linode

I'm running a little Drupal site on a little Linode server. All I want is for Drupal to be able to send a little system email with an account login link (which uses PHP's `mail()` function). I don't want to receive mail, and I don't really care what the From email address is. Just a simple little login email.

From what I'm reading, this is just about the most difficult thing anyone could ever want to do... you have to follow opaque 1000-step guides and spend hours and days setting up an entire mail server.

Is it ***really*** that hard? I'm having trouble believing that it is. Linode has already unblocked the requisite ports for me. So, I repeat:

Is it ***really*** that hard? No one has ever done this without setting up a whole mail server (or paying for a third-party service)?

Comment: If you can't configure a mail server, you are free to pay for Amazon SES, Mailgun, you name it. At the same time, their configuration also takes time (and money).

Comment: At the same time it seems that your hoster is [blocking mailing ports](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/19082/i-just-created-my-first-linode-and-i-cant-send-emails-why-mailing-ports-25-465-a) by default. This adds some extra fun to your journey.

Comment: Ah, they have unblocked the ports... so that variable is out of the equation.